# Is the Jallikattu festival connected to Hinduism? If so, what is its significance?

Tags: rituals, culture, tradition, festivals

The famous [Jallikattu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jallikattu) festival of Tamil Nadu, India was temporarily banned and then reinstated recently. My questions are:

- Is the Jallikattu festival connected to Hinduism?
- If so, what is the significance of Jallikattu according to Hinduism?
- Are there any Hindu rituals associated with this festival?

Comment: Jallikattu has no relation with Hinduism. So, i'm voting to close your question as offtopic.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, no.. taming bulls is definitely related to our culture. Even Srimad Bhagavatam & Tamil Prabandhams, mentions Sri Krishna taming 7 bulls to marry a Gopi

Comment: It is a traditional spring festival - happens the day after Makara Sankranti. Since that is harvest time for crops, and bulls usually did all the work of ploughing the field, they are very strong after exercising, and any men who tame such bulls are fit to face hardships later in life, so fathers give their daughters in marriage to such brave men. Recently, Supreme court banned the practice citing cruelty to animals.. and conveniently ignores all the other cruelty happening in slaughter houses.

Comment: @ram ok. Write an answer how Jallikattu is related to Hinduism.

Comment: This question needs to be reopened. It is very much a part of 'veerya shulka' (condition of bravery for marriage) done in past by our kings. Bhagavan himself did this.

Links for reference - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagnajiti

http://www.srimadbhagavatamclass.com/srimad-bhagavatam-canto-10-chapter-58-text-45/

Comment: It is cultural in significance; not religious.

Comment: @ram Can you write an answer how Jalikattu is related to Hinduism? Above verses from Bhagavatam doesn't say how they are related to Hinduism. It's cultural than religious or Spiritual,

Comment: @ram The current jallikattu is not practised as a test of fitness of a potential husband. Hence the example is not applicable. In Hinduism, it is a sin to inflict cruelty on animals for sport and pleasure.

Comment: "Jallikattu" is a part of celebration called Pongal in Tamil Nadu as a respect given to the Language and Farmers. Which is connected to devotional aspect for the language. As the sage Agasthiya the one who gave the grammar for the language is a devotee of the lord Shiva the only God who gave the foremost respect to the language as he himself came and acknowledged the songs written to him by his devotee... And also the play Jallikattu is to show the Valor of the youth in Tamil Nadu, with the lords bull as a playful act...

Comment: @moonstar2001, there are a lot of religious rituals that have lost their true meaning over time, for e.g. kasi yatra in marriages where the groom is ready to renounce the world.. which groom really feels that way today ? does that mean we stop doing it.. No. I agree that it is cruel to inflict pain on animals(like tying crackers to their tail or putting chili powder in eyes), but the goal should be to remove the cruelty, not the sport itself.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, anything Lord Krishna did is dear to his bhaktas. Bhakti is one of the pillars of hinduism. So taming bulls reminds us of Krishna's valor and hence it is a part of hinduism. Various geographical regions have varying cultures but if it is part of what Krishna (or Shiva) did, then it is part of hinduism. Another instance where lot of youth participate is uri-adi festival (trying to break a pot tied high up while others try to prevent you).

Comment: @ram, explain how it's related to Hinduism? what is the significance? The term Jallikattu or Sallikattu is derived from salli (coins) and kattu (package), which refers to a prize of coins that are tied to the bull's horns and that participants attempt to retrieve. It's literally "bull embracing". May be ancestors did it for cultural practice and now a days people who did this is literally torturing bulls name of tradition. More often portrayed jallikattu as a symbol of masculinity and social status, so we strongly believe it's no where related to Hinuism.

Comment: @CR241 'Eru Thazhuvuthal' literally means Bull Embracing and is another term for the same practice not the term 'Jallikattu'